# How to give news of my grandmothers death

Tags: translation, meaning, mandarin

In English I would say: I am sorry to say my grandmother passed away on X date.

How would I give that news in mandarin? Is there a way to say ‘I am sorry to say’ or do they not say that in mandarin?

Answer (score 2):

When delivering sad or bad news, a common phrase to say is 很不幸，很遺憾，or 很抱歉

Example:

**很不幸**, 我心愛的寵物積克已經去世了 - **unfortunately/ sadly**, my beloved pet Jack has passed away. (He was such a good boy)

**很遺憾**, 你這次測試你失敗了 - **regretfully**, you have failed this test

**很抱歉**, 我對你一點好感也沒有 - **Sorry**, I don't have any good feelings for you

> I am sorry to say my grandmother passed away on X date

很不幸, 我的祖母在 X月X日 去世了

Answer (score 1):

"I am sorry to say". This type of expression is not in the Chinese's blood for the described event - the pass away of a family member. Rather the news is usually announced as a family matter:

"家中不幸". 我的祖母在前天晚間過逝了,  她走的很突然但是很安祥.

"家中不幸" will be dropped for a person without any attachment/tie to his family or have any living closely related family members around, that who is considered no home/family.

"很不幸", 我的祖母在前天過逝了. This will be an answer to another person, who is asking the whereabout/condition of the grandmother without knowing her death.